# How to trace reason for system crash after reboot?

Tags: firefox

I was running Firefox, two tabs one with Youtube and my system froze and required hard reboot.

Is there a way to find the cause of the crash after a system reboot?
Does Ubuntu auto log crashes?

Answer (score 2):

There is possibly an answer in the syslog file.

Search for 'log' in the dash and 'log file viewer' should come up, I then usually comb over the log for anything that stands out, like look at the log and see what happened just before your computer rebooted, if it's got anything interesting like errors or crashes I usually google the line to see what other people are saying.

Comment: I'll check that out next time my system crashes, thanks. Seems to be an issue when I run youtube videos in firefox. Gets stuck and freezes up whole system. Is there a way to kill a process to avoid having to hard reboot?

Comment: yeah definitely, my command line system monitor of sorts is htop.

`sudo apt-get install htop`

Use / to find firefox and F9 to kill it.

You can usually get into the command line by pressing ctrl + alt + f1 and ctrl + alt + f7 to get back to your main screen.